# What does "s.a" mean in this generate_series() query

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

I'm trying this for returning business days, but I don´t understand `s.a` and `s(a)` in this query:

```
SELECT dia 
FROM (
    SELECT ('2012-08-01'::date + s.a * '1 day'::interval) AS dia
    FROM generate_series(0, '2012-08-31'::date - '2012-08-01'::date, 1) AS s(a)
) foo
WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM dia) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
EXCEPT
SELECT feriado_data FROM teste.feriado;
```

Could someone explain it for me?

Answer (score 11):

`s` in `s(a)` is a *table alias* given to the set returned by `generate_series` and the `a` in `s(a)` is the alias given to its only column.

Refer to [table expression docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) and scroll to 
"Another form of table aliasing gives temporary names to the columns of the table" for full details.

Comment: why we sum date with s.a in the first sub-select?

Comment: I found this very helpful when trying to understand a sample I found elsewhere. But it's missing the keyword "table alias" that would have been useful to include.